# C : write to video ram

Tags: c, low-level, video-memory

I am trying to make a function that would write strings to video memory with a specific color. However, I am unable to make it work. To write single characters, i would do this:

```
*(char *)0xb8000 = 'O'; //Prints the letter O at the first position in video memory
*(char *)0xb8001 = 'O'; //Adds it some colors (Haven't figured how to write a byte here)
```

But I need to write with a variable, so I tried this but it just prints nothing.

```
int currentAddressVRAM = 0xb8000;

*(char *)currentAddressVRAM = 'O';
currentAddressVRAM++;

*(char *)currentAddressVRAM = 'O';
currentAddressVRAM++;
```

How would I do this?  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I tried this too and it just printed nothing:

```
char *currentAddressVRAM = (char *)0xb8000;

*currentAddressVRAM = 'O';
currentAddressVRAM++;

*currentAddressVRAM = 'O';
currentAddressVRAM++;
```

Comment: Are you sure that on the platform you are working on an `int` is large enough to hold `0xb8000`? And why not store a pointer to the VRAM address directly, such as `char *vram = 0xb8000;`? Why store the address in an integer?

Comment: My environment is this virtual machine (executable) : qemu-system-x86_64.

Comment: tbh, I don't know how to store the memory adress. I used int because I thought it was logical, but it might not be that

Comment: Please try the proposed changes (using a wider int and using a pointer) and report the results. Both are plausible enough to merit that effort.

Comment: In case that 0x8000 is read-writeable (not necessarily legally...) please check whether the `'O'` ends up there.

Comment: Here you can find information about the color values: https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI#Colours

Comment: The color is not the problem. If I make the color : (char)0x0A It still does not work even tho it would be light green on black.

Comment: How would I make sure that the O ends up there? It runs on an emulator with no OS so I can't use printf to print the value of that place in memory

Comment: Can you do anything notable? Like shutdown on equality vs. hang on inequality?

Comment: I would expect these codes to be equivalent. Check the assembly code your compiler generates. See what's different.

Comment: Can't you move the first to the second character like `*(char *)0xb8002 = *(char *)0xb8000`?

Comment: Maybe this might help- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638857/19323916

Comment: @Kolodez: No, in C, integer literals have a type wide enough to hold the value.  On a system with 16-bit `int`, 0xb8000 would have type `long`.  (`unsigned long` is also an option before `long long` for literals with no suffix, or for non-decimal bases).  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it finally!
Thanks for all of your helpful comments, it help me find the solution to my problem.
Here is my code :

```
#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xb8000

void PrintS(char *text, char color)
{
    char *currentAddressVRAM = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY;
    for (int i = 0; 1; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        *currentAddressVRAM++ = text[i];
        *currentAddressVRAM++ = color;
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that I don't know how to save the current address between the uses of the function. If somebody knows, please let me know!

Comment: A global variable of pointer type would be the obvious choice. Like  `struct VGA_char { char txt, attrib;} *cursor = (void*)VIDEO_MEMORY;`

Comment: Your `if()break` could very easily and readably the loop condition inside the for loop, like `for(int i=0 ; text[i] != 0 ; i++) {`